# In Excel formula, how to increment a date by 1 but with fixed time based on conditions

Tags: excel-formula

Let's say, i have a cell A1 with date/time value as 15/3/2016 13:00. 
Using a formula, I want to set the date in another cell with the following condition:

- **IF** A1's time is greater than 13:00 hours and A1+1 (Next day) is not equal to Weekend (Sat and Sun) or Holiday, **THEN** set B1 as 16/3/2016 09:00 **ELSE** set B1 as next working day with time as 09:00 hour.

Comment: What formula have you tried so far and what is it doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have Five components for this.

Checking the time:

```
TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1), SECOND(A1)) > TIME(HOUR(0.54166666),MINUTE(0), SECOND(0)
```

Checking tomorrows day of week:

```
TEXT(DAY(A1),"dddd")<>"Saturday",TEXT(DAY(A1),"dddd")<>"Sunday")
```

Checking if tomorrow is a holiday:

```
iserror(vlookup(DATE(YEAR(A1+1),MONTH(A1+1),DAY(A1+1)),c1:c5,1,false))
```

Output Tomorrow +1 day at 9am

```
DATE(YEAR(A1+1),MONTH(A1+1),DAY(A1+1))+0.375
```

Output Next workday at 9am

```
WORKDAY(A1,1,C1:C5)+0.375
```

This requires a holiday list.  For my sample I put some in C1:C5, but you can put stuff wherever.

Completed IF statement example:

```
=IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1), SECOND(A1)) > TIME(HOUR(0.54166666),MINUTE(0), SECOND(0)),AND(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(DATE(YEAR(A1+1),MONTH(A1+1),DAY(A1+1)),C1:C5,1,FALSE)),TEXT(DAY(A1),"dddd")<>"Saturday",TEXT(DAY(A1),"dddd")<>"Sunday")),DATE(YEAR(A1+1),MONTH(A1+1),DAY(A1+1))+0.375,WORKDAY(A1,1,C1:C5)+0.375)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Alan for the response... Will check with your inputs